# How to change the string to class object in another file

Tags: python, string, class, object, module

I already use this function to change some string to class object.

But now I have defined a new module. How can I implement the same functionality?

```
def str2class(str):
    return getattr(sys.modules[__name__], str)
```

I want to think some example, but it is hard to think. Anyway, the main problem is maybe the file path problem.

If you really need an example, the GitHub code is [here](https://github.com/a358003542/wise-system/blob/master/Chain.py).

The Chain.py file needs to perform an auto action mechanism. Now it fails.

**New approach:**
Now I put all files under one filefold, and it works, but if I use the modules concept, it fails. So if the problem is in a module file, how can I change the string object to relative class object?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to achieve, but I'm pretty sure you're going about it the wrong way. This question is very unclear; see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/3001761

Comment: If you want to use the function from another file, just import it with`from Chain import str2class`

Comment: no , it is not about use the function in another file , but the class object already exist , and how to use the same class object with the same string name (in another files).o ,maybe i need put the object write  in a file and read it ?

Comment: Please explain the problem you are trying to solve with this solution.

Comment: Don't put answers in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by accessing the namespace of the module directly:

```
import module
f = module.__dict__["func_name"]
# f is now a function and can be called:
f()
```

One of the greatest things about Python is that the internals are accessible to you, and that they fit the language paradigm. A name (of a variable, class, function, whatever) in a namespace is actually just a key in a dictionary that maps to that name's value.

If you're interested in what other language internals you can play with, try running `dir()` on things. You'd be surprised by the number of hidden methods available on most of the objects.

Answer (score 0):

You probably should write this function like this:

```
def str2class(s):
    return globals()[s]
```

It's really clearer and works even if `__name__` is set to `__main__`.

Comment: yes , in the same files , the function also works , but in another file can do it ,sorry,